# Asynchronous Blocking Request in Javascript: Return value from async function

Tags: javascript, typescript, async-await

I am using async and await for achieving this. Following is my code and it is working as expected.

```
function publish() {    
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(function () {
      resolve("SUCCESS");
    }, 3000);  
  });
}
var res;
async function sendRequest() {
  console.log("START\n");
  res = await publish();
  console.log("RESULT: ",res)
  console.log("END\n");
}
sendRequest();
```

Following is the output:

```
START

SUCCESS

END
```

But what I am trying to achieve is given below:

```
function publish() {    
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(function () {
      resolve("SUCCESS");
    }, 3000);    
  });
}
var res;
async function sendRequest() {
  console.log("START\n");
  res = await publish();
  console.log("RESULT: ",res)
  console.log("END\n");
  return res;
}

/**
 * EXPECTED BEHAVIOUR
 * Assume this function is an action of a controller class
 * It will call sendRequest() and waits for its response.
 * Once received, it will return that response to the client who called the action.
 */
function controller () {
  return sendRequest();
}    
/**
 * ACTUAL BEHAVIOUR: It will out put following
 * START
 * FINAL RESPONSE Promise { <pending> } 
 * RESULT:  SUCCESS
 * SEND
 */
var endResult = controller (); 
console.log("FINAL RESPONSE",endResult);
```

So my question is why this `FINAL RESPONSE Promise { <pending> }` is printed before `RESULT:  SUCCESS`.

- If this is the behaviour of `async` `await`, how can I achieve my
  expected behaviour. I don't want to use `then()` in my controller.
- Is it possible using while loop? May be I am wrong. It would be great
  if any one can guide me.

Comment: "I don't want to use then() in my controller" — Too bad.

Comment: Await does not make your code `sync`,.. You can only wait a async method from a async callee..  IOW: You will need another `async` method to wrap your waiting inside.

Comment: "Is it possible using while loop?" — Not in any way that is remotely helpful.

Comment: Is there any other approach other than await and async?

Comment: `then`, is the only other option.  All the `async` method is doing is making the function into a Promise, as such you can either await from any async, or use the `then` callback.

Comment: @Keith So you mean my controller should be async await function right?

Comment: Your controller is already implicitly returning a Promise anyway.   So you just can do `controller().then(() => {}`

Comment: the `controller()` method is not awaiting `sendRequest`, therefore it will return immediately

Comment: @Jim,  no it's returning a Promise..

Comment: @KirenSiva the below answers enough to guide. But please do lookup on coding with `promises` and `async/await` just another way of rearranging the promise code. Just remember **Once an Promise, Always a Promise** till its resolved.

Comment: @Keith your statements are true to the purpose. Good job.

Comment: I am checking all the comments and answers to solve the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`async..await` is syntactic sugar for promises that provides syncronous-like flow of control. `async` function is just a function that always returns a promise. Each `async` function can be rewritten as regular function that uses `Promise` explicitly and returns a promise.

> I don't want to use then() in my controller.

Then `controller` can optionally be `async`, and the function where it is called should be `async`:

```
let endResult = await controller();
```

Otherwise control flow results in [this infamous problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call).

> Is it possible using while loop?

`while` and other loop statements support `async..await`. As long as the loop is performed inside `async` function, it is:

```
while (condition) {
    let endResult = await controller();
    // ...
}
```

It's preferable to use `async..await` for this purpose, because desugared version is less appealing and harder to comprehend:

```
let resultsPromise = Promise.resolve();

while (condition) {
    resultsPromise = resultsPromise
    .then(() => controller())
    .then(endResult => {
        // ...
    });
}

resultsPromise.then(() => { /* loop has finished */ })
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to handle the last `async` function as a `Promise`, like:

```
function controller () {
  return sendRequest()
}

controller().then(endResult => console.log("FINAL RESPONSE",endResult))
```

Comment: The `async` keyword on controller is doing nothing here.

Comment: Well, makes sense because the `sendRequest` returns a `Promise`.

Comment: The await statement is required... The promise will show as resolved before it is actually resolved

Comment: @NickProzee  No it won't  `sendRequest` is returning a Promise, all the controller here will be doing is returning the `Promise` that sendRequest has already created..  The await will be wrapping a Promise inside a Promise, a pointless thing to do..

Comment: He edited the post, before it had the async in front of it. So in that example the promise would have resolved before actually resolving. Indeed, removing the async statement is a cleaner option

Comment: @NickProzee Indeed, I see what you mean now.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a wrapper function

```js
// Code goes here
(async function(){

function publish() {

  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(function () {
      resolve("SUCCESS");
    }, 3000);

  });
}

var res;

async function sendRequest() {
  console.log("START\n");
  res = await publish();
  console.log("RESULT: ",res)
  console.log("END\n");
  return res;
}

/**
 * EXPECTED BEHAVIOUR
 * Assume this function is an action of a controller class
 * It will call sendRequest() and waits for its response.
 * Once received, it will return that response to the client who called the action.
 */
function controller () {
  return sendRequest();
}

/**
 * ACTUAL BEHAVIOUR: It will out put following
 * START
 * FINAL RESPONSE Promise { <pending> } 
 * RESULT:  SUCCESS
 * SEND
 */
var endResult = await  controller (); 
console.log("FINAL RESPONSE",endResult);
}())
```